# Newer version of Docker gives permission errors during build

Tags: docker, docker-build, rhapsody

I've created a Dockerfile to install IBM Rational Rhapsody on a 32bit Ubuntu image, which builds correctly with Docker 18.03.0-ce on Windows 7 but fails with Docker 18.09.2 on a Linux Mint 19 VM (Ubuntu Bionic repos). IBM's Java-based installer throws a permissions issue, and the Docker changelogs didn't show any obvious reasons for this.

The Dockerfile up to the failing command is as follows:

```
FROM i386/ubuntu:xenial-20181005 AS installation

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unzip

COPY Rhapsody812Linux.zip .
RUN unzip -qq Rhapsody812Linux.zip -d Rhapsody812Linux

RUN cd Rhapsody812Linux/disk1/im/installer.linux.gtk.x86 \
    && ./installc input install-rhapsody.xml -acceptLicense
```

The failure I'm seeing is:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Failed to create artifact table of contents at '/var/ibm/InstallationManager/installRegistry/metadata'.
  ...IBM's library stack trace truncated by me...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
  at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$1.release(FileChannelImpl.java:115)
  at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$SimpleFileLockTable.removeAll(FileChannelImpl.java:1024)
  at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.implCloseChannel(FileChannelImpl.java:112)
  at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:108)
  ...IBM's library stack trace truncated by me...
ERROR: Error restoring Installation Manager state.
  ERROR:   Failed to create InstallRegistry metadata repository: /var/ibm/InstallationManager/installRegistry/metadata.
```

I found a forum post stating this can happen if `/tmp` isn't accessible, which it seems to be:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 18 20:35 /tmp
```

I ran an Ubuntu Xenial image interactively to see what I could find out, and the installer does create `/var/ibm/InstallationManager/installRegistry/metadata` so I'm not sure where the permission issue is coming from.

What could be different between these Docker versions, and how can I resolve this build failure in the newer version?

Comment: For clarification, the Windows host is using the aufs storage driver but none of aufs, overlay, nor overlay2 worked on the Linux VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the installer multiple times consecutively, I got a "CRIMC1086E ERROR" and found an [IBM Knowledge Center entry](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.4.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.4/distr/src_pi/awspiinstmlp.htm) mentioning this code. It suggests disabling the IBM Installation Manager's repository locking, which resolved the issue for me.

To disable the repository lock, add `cic.repo.locking=false` to `config.ini`. In my case, I made the following addition to my Dockerfile:

```
# Disable repo lock to avoid potential permissions issue when lock is released
# Experienced with Docker 18.09.2 on a Linux Mint 19 VM
RUN cd Rhapsody812Linux/disk1/im/installer.linux.gtk.x86/configuration \
    && echo 'cic.repo.locking=false' >> config.ini
```