# How do I install IBM Rational Rhapsody on Ubuntu as a dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build, rhapsody

[Newer version of Docker gives permission errors during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230329/newer-version-of-docker-gives-permission-errors-during-build)

This post talks about creating a dockerfile for a Rhapsody installation on Ubuntu.  I'm a Rhapsody expert but not a Ubuntu or dockerfile expert.

How should I install Rhapsody on Ubuntu?
The documentation talks about 2 ways - using IBM Installation Manager or just starting launchpad.sh (which apparently then uses IBM Installation Manager anyway).  I guess I do this manually on Ubuntu to create the zip file which I then download in my dockerfile?

Do I just do

```
sudo /launchpad.sh
```

The IBM prerequisites are apparently -

Rhapsody is a 32-bit application and requires 32-bit versions of OS libraries. These libraries are not installed on RHEL x86_64 (64-bit) by default. You must install these 32-bit libraries on your system before you run Installation Manager:

> gtk2.i686  libXtst.i686  PackageKit-gtk-module.i686 
>   libcanberra-gtk2.i686  gtk2-engines.i686  libXdmcp.i686  libXmu.i686
>   libXft.i686 libXrender.i686

How do I install these on Ubuntu?  Do they even exist?
Can I install 32-bit libs in 64-bit Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is unclear.

Would you like to install Rhapsody on Linux?
Or run Rhapsody in a container on Linux?

The 2 approaches are effectively alternatives.

There are 2 ways to run an application (e.g. Rhapsody) as a container (often Docker) image.

The first (and easiest) is to hope that a trustworthy entity (perhaps IBM in this case) has created a definitive image for you already. This appears to not be the case with IBM and Rhapsody as I was unable to find such an image on Docker image repository. There are Rhapsody [images](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=rhapsody&type=image) on Docker Hub but a cursory review does not include an IBM official image:

The second is to create your own container image. To do this you generally use a Dockerfile (as shown in the post that you reference) and you then use Docker Engine and build the image (`docker build --tag=rhapsody --file=Dockerfile .` often abbreviated to `docker build --tag=rhapsody .`).

You can then use Docker Engine to run the image (and thus your application).